# Second App Bar in Android

Tags: android

As seen below, my application currently has a second App Bar that stacks below the second. And the unfortunate part is I have absolutely no idea how it is happening, as this has happened as a result of a merge by Git, so I have no idea what code is the offender.
The reason the above bar is a different colour is the bottom bar is the colour it is initially, declared in the xml file, but then I changed the colour of the top programatically to confirm there are two bars and it isn't just a size problem.

[image]

I'm aware that since I can't really post any code due to the lack of any ideas as to the source of the error this is a bit of a shot in the dark, however is there anything I should check to try determine the cause?

And yes, application theme has the app bar disabled. The really funky thing as well is if I extend my base UI class to another activity so it has the App Bar as well, only one bar is displayed, see below.

[image]

EDIT: As per request.
Manifest:

```
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="Page Title"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!--<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You need to post the XML of this part otherwise we will endup guessing.

Comment: Show your menifest and style

Comment: Check the layout for the activity or fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
```

- use this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); to hide the
  title Bar
- if you want show like first top image then make layout for that
  imnstead of using two different appBar